# Nothing being rendered when running npm run serve on basic Vue tutorial

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following the beginner tutorial on Vue.js here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4deVCNJq3qc

I believe I have followed the code precisely, but I just see a blank page (no error messages) when I run `npm run serve` and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/`

[image]

Here is the content in each of the relevant files:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
      <app></app>
    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  components: {
    App
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

`Header.vue` (located in components)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-nav>
      <b-nav-item active>Fancy Quiz App</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item>Counter: 4/10</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

`QuestionBox.vue` located in components:

```
<template>
    <h1> Question Box </h1>
</template>
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "wikipedia-coedit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Dev Tools sources window shows this for `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>wikipedia-coedit</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but wikipedia-coedit doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
      <app></app>

    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate any help -- I've just begun learning this.

Comment: If nothing served what does happen when you load that url in browser? Any errors in node console?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm using "nothing served" incorrectly.  After running npm run serve it compiles successfully, but the URL shows a blank screen.

Comment: When you say "no content" do you mean you just see a blank/white page or some kind of error message? Also can you please post your serve script from your package.json?

Comment: Is it a 404 error in dev tools network?

Comment: It's just a blank page.  No error message.  And I posted the entirety of package.json just now.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what status is and what is sent. Really not much debugging detail here for us to work with

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I'm new to this.  Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: With url in address bar....hit F12 and dev tools will open. Look at network tab then drill down on the index.html request. Can see the content, status, headers etc of every request made, html, js, images etc there

Comment: Not sure what content I'm supposed to be finding, but in the sources tab in the dev tools window, I found index.html and posted it's content just now

Comment: OK...in the `console` tab any errors? Can also add some regular html (outside <app>) in that file temporarily just for display to see it is being loaded but what you show from sources looks right on first glance

Comment: @charlietfl good catch.  Check this error out in console.  What does this mean: https://imgur.com/Aa8OD2Z?

Comment: Add that in text in question. My vue background is really minimal. Getting to that point of error discovery though was critical or all we are doing on this end is guessing. Good lesson...start in console always

Comment: Can confirm text is loaded when outside the app tags

Comment: Problem is the error preventing the app to compile and render. Would also do  search of that error message. Likely a common one with vue apps

Comment: You shouldn't need to add App as a component in main.js, or in Index.html. Try removing that, to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Can you provide the `App.vue` content? I can't reproduce the bug with the `App.vue` I found in the video. Anw, can you run the example from the git link under the video?